# Opening a jquery dialog from a sibling link element without using ID-based selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I've been trying to wrap my head around a seemingly simple problem using jQuery UI's dialog feature.  On a particular search results page, each of the results may contain some notations with help links.  Each help link will ideally open a dialog box containing a custom explanation for that specific item.  A snippet of the HTML for the results might look like this:

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>Text (<a class='helplink' href='#'>?</a>)
            <div class='dialog' title='mytitle'>Here's some dialog text</div>
        </td>
        <td>Text 2 (<a class='helplink' href='#'>?</a>)
            <div class='dialog' title='mytitle2'>Here's some dialog text for result 2</div>
        </td>
</tr>
```

I had originally figured that I could bind the click event to the anchor and use the next('div.dialog') selector to find and show the dialog.  But once the div is processed by the dialog'ifier, it moves elsewhere in the dom and is no longer a sibling.  Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnzrhwf4/1/) of what I was trying to accomplish.

Can anyone recommend a better way to do this?  While I could hypothetically use some data from each result to generate a unique ID for each element, I'm really trying to avoid that and have something more elegant.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: You could use HTML5 data attributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: I thought about that but it feels clunky because I'm still generating unique IDs for each element.

Comment: jQuery moves all dialogs to the end of the body so you'll have to forget trying to select them by the hierarchy that you create and either use just one dialog and change the contents, or find a way to associate your dialogs with the links in order to be able to reference them.

Comment: Using a single dialog may end up working if I just store the dialog data as data attributes in the link element and populate it before showing it.  Regarding the association between elements, is there any standard way to do that?

Comment: Pawel had a good use of custom data attributes. It's what I'd use.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on testing that now using your idea of a single shared dialog that gets updated with the appropriate content.

Answer (score 0):

So based on the comments, here's the solution I'm currently working with.  Instead of having a unique dialog instance per help link, there is a single shared dialog box.  Data attributes are used on the link element in order to store the link specific title and body of the dialog.  When the link is clicked, the common dialog is updated with the link specific values and opened.  Because the dialog content can hypothetically containd html, I'm still rendering that data in a div in the original html next to the link, then using jQuery to copy it into the data attribute rather than trying to render it and deal with escaping everything.

Here is the resulting code and a link to the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnzrhwf4/2/).

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td>Text (<a class='helplink' href='#' data-title='mytitle'>?</a>)
        <div class='content'>test text with <a href='#'>link</a></div>
    </td>
    <td>Text 2 (<a class='helplink' href='#' data-title='mytitle2'>?</a>)
        <div class='content'>test text 2 with <a href='#'>link2</a></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="commonDialog" title="origTitle">origContent</div>
```

and

```
$(function () {
    $('#commonDialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        closeOnEscape: true
    });
    $('a.helplink').each(function () {
        // copy the div content into the data attribute and remove the div
        $(this).data('content', $(this).siblings('div.content').html());
        $(this).siblings('div.content').remove();
    }).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // populate the dialog title and body
        var d = $('#commonDialog');
        d.html($(this).data('content'));
        d.siblings('.ui-dialog-titlebar').children('span').text($(this).data('title'));
        // and display it
        d.dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Any additional recommendations on cleaning up my selectors or other improvements are welcome.